# Nothing happens when using "Edit in Microsoft Excel" button in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-excel

The user is trying to edit a sharepoint document. It works on every other computer, just not on this particular one. All computers are running IE and Office. I'm used to seeing the "This document is locked out to.." error, but in this case nothing at all happens.

Comment: It would be very helpful to know which version of SharePoint and whether or not you're using Excel Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a problem with the ActiveX control provided by the Office client products that give this additional functionality. Try the following:

1. If you have pre-Office 2007 products installed on the machine, run Setup and remove the **Windows SharePoint Services Support** component.
2. For each Office 2007 product, run Setup and ensure the **Windows SharePoint Services Support** component is installed (under Office Tools).
3. You may also need to **Repair** the Office 2007 product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably stating the obvious here (and fully expect to get down-voted for it), but have you checked that Excel is installed correctly on the problem computer?

It could be that the installation on that computer is damaged, so a repair might fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue. Repaired Office and it was fixed. (Add/Remove Programs > Office > Change > Repair)